# Angular texarea to array pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I have textarea used to display the rows(and length) from an array on many pages in my app, which is working fine with `toArray()`, but I have a lots of duplicate code for each textarea to get/set values to array and join back to string to display.

Is there any pipe I can use instead `toArray` function on each component to convert an array to string with new lines('\n') for display/edit purpose and convert it back to array for API?

HTML

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" [(ngModel)]="item.color" (ngModelChange)="toArray($event)"></textarea>
```

Convert to array (multiple function of similar type)

```
  colorArray(value: string): void {
    this.item.color = value.split(/[\r\n]+/);
  }
  patternArray(value: string): void {
    this.item.pattern= value.split(/[\r\n]+/);
  }
  ...
```

Item

```
{
 name : 'event',
 color: ['red','black','blue'] 
}
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I think you have to create a custom pipe for it.
But I don't understand where you have lots of duplicate code, and how a pipe can make it better?

Comment: The dupes code is these functions `colorArray`, `patternArray`, `xyzArray()`, `abcArray()`

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="item.color"` is merely a shorthand syntax for `[ngModel]="item.color" (ngModelChange)="item.color=$event"` as explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding). You cannot use any expression here, including pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom textarea component that applies this regex to a input and displays it. Plus, the output could always be an array(or anything you want).

```js
//textareaComponent.ts
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-textarea',
  template: `
    <textarea clas="form-control" rows="3" [(ngModel)]="_color" (ngModelChange)="_onColorsChange()"></textarea>
  `
})
export class TextareaComponent {
  @Input() set colors(value: string[]) {//receives an array of colors and converts it to a string
    this._color = value.join('\n');
  }
  @Output() $onColorsChange = new EventEmitter<string[]>();//emits an array
  public _color: string = ''

  public _onColorsChange(): void {//emits an array to the parent component
    this.$onColorsChange.emit(_color.split(/[\r\n]+/));
  }
}

//ParentComponent.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <app-textarea
      [colors]="arrayOfColors"
      ($onColorsChange)="doSomethingWithTheArrayOfColors(colors)"></app-texttextarea>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  public arrayOfColors: string[];

  public doSomethingWithTheArrayOfColors(colors: string[]): void {
    console.log(colors);//should print an array on every change on the textarea
  }
```

Comment: I can't make it working. Can you please post the working code on stackblitz. It gives me a prototype but the event emitter doesn't change the original array values.

Comment: Hope it helps.
[code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-vaughan-4kfen)

Comment: thanks, that's a lot of help. I am very thankful to you!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you cannot do it completely with pipes itself. You have to do it two parts, one of which is pipe and another is generic toArray function.

This pipe will convert string array to string row. Don't forget to import pipe in the module.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'toStringRows'
})
export class ToStringRowsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: unknown, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
    var cleaned = [].concat(value).join('\n');
    return cleaned;
  }

}
```

This generic method will convert string back to array and assign to the value to the model.

```
 toArray(item, prop, event){
     item[prop] = event.split(/[\r\n]+/);
     console.log(this.item.color);
     console.log(this.item.pattern);
   }
```

The following is how you will use it for different values.

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  [ngModel]="item.color |  toStringRows" (ngModelChange)="toArray(item,'color', $event)"></textarea>


<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" [ngModel]="item.pattern | toStringRows" (ngModelChange)="toArray(item,'pattern', $event)"></textarea>
```